# Pandas groupby, resample, return NaN not 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {"timestamp": ["2022-12-15 22:00:00", "2022-12-15 22:00:30", "2022-12-15 22:00:47", 
                        "2022-12-15 22:00:03", "2022-12-15 22:00:30", "2022-12-15 22:00:43", 
                        "2022-12-15 22:00:10", "2022-12-15 22:00:34", "2022-12-15 22:00:59"],
        "ID": ["A","A","A",
                "B", "B", "B",
                "C", "C", "C"],
        "value": [11, 0, 0,
                    7, 5, 7,
                    0, 3.4, 3.4]
    }

df_test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["timestamp", "ID", "value"])
df_test["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df_test["timestamp"])
```

I want to create a new dataframe which for every ID has a row for every second from "2022-12-15 22:00:00" to "2022-12-15 22:01:00" in the same dataframe. So the end dataframe will have 180 rows (60 for each ID, so each rows is one second in the timeinterval.). For the rows which match the `timestamp` in `df_test` I want the `value` and otherwise I want a `NaN` value.

I have tried using the following code:

```
df_resampled = df_test.groupby("ID").resample("S", on="timestamp").sum().reset_index()
```

But this have the problem that for rows which do not match, 0 is returned instead of `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "value" issue itself could be fixed as follows:

```
res = (df_test.set_index('timestamp')
       .groupby('ID')
       .resample('S')
       .asfreq()['value']
       .reset_index())

res.shape
# (139, 3) N.B. Wrong start and end!
```

However, this won't solve another problem that consists of the fact that a simple `resample` will start/end with the first/last timestamp for each `ID`, and in your example these are not always `22:00:00` and `22:00:59`.

Here's an alternative approach:

- Use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) to create a range for the 60 seconds.
- Use [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) to create a new index that combines [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) applied to column `ID` and the date range we have just created (`rng`). (Make sure to use the ranges in this order!)
- Now, we can simply use [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to make `ID` and `timestamp` the index, apply [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), and finally, apply [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) again.

```
rng = pd.date_range(start='2022-12-15 22:00:00', end='2022-12-15 22:00:59', 
                    freq="S")

multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_test.ID.unique(), rng],
                                         names=['ID', 'timestamp'])

res = df_test.set_index(['ID','timestamp']).reindex(multi_index).reset_index()

# check result
res[(res.value.notna()) | 
    (res.timestamp.isin(['2022-12-15 22:00:00', '2022-12-15 22:00:59']))]

    ID           timestamp  value
0    A 2022-12-15 22:00:00   11.0
30   A 2022-12-15 22:00:30    0.0
47   A 2022-12-15 22:00:47    0.0
59   A 2022-12-15 22:00:59    NaN
60   B 2022-12-15 22:00:00    NaN
63   B 2022-12-15 22:00:03    7.0
90   B 2022-12-15 22:00:30    5.0
103  B 2022-12-15 22:00:43    7.0
119  B 2022-12-15 22:00:59    NaN
120  C 2022-12-15 22:00:00    NaN
130  C 2022-12-15 22:00:10    0.0
154  C 2022-12-15 22:00:34    3.4
179  C 2022-12-15 22:00:59    3.4

# Note that all the zeros are still there, 
# and that each `ID` starts/ends with the correct timestamp

res.shape
# (180, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get unique 'ID'
2. Make temporary (tmp) DataFrame with first and last time (2022-12-15 22:00:00', '2022-12-15 22:00:59')
3. Merge df_test and tmp
4. Resample

   ```
    l = list(df_test['ID'].unique())    
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({'ID': l * 2, 'timestamp': 
          [df_test['timestamp'].iloc[0]]*len(l)
        + [df_test['timestamp'].iloc[-1]]*len(l)})
    tmp = pd.merge_ordered(df_test, tmp, on = ['ID','timestamp'])
    result = (tmp.set_index('timestamp')
         .groupby('ID')
         .resample('S')
         .asfreq()['value']
         .reset_index())
   ```

result:

```
0    A 2022-12-15 22:00:00   11.0
1    A 2022-12-15 22:00:01    NaN
2    A 2022-12-15 22:00:02    NaN
3    A 2022-12-15 22:00:03    NaN
4    A 2022-12-15 22:00:04    NaN
5    A 2022-12-15 22:00:05    NaN
6    A 2022-12-15 22:00:06    NaN
7    A 2022-12-15 22:00:07    NaN
8    A 2022-12-15 22:00:08    NaN
9    A 2022-12-15 22:00:09    NaN
10   A 2022-12-15 22:00:10    NaN
11   A 2022-12-15 22:00:11    NaN
12   A 2022-12-15 22:00:12    NaN
13   A 2022-12-15 22:00:13    NaN
14   A 2022-12-15 22:00:14    NaN
15   A 2022-12-15 22:00:15    NaN
16   A 2022-12-15 22:00:16    NaN
17   A 2022-12-15 22:00:17    NaN
18   A 2022-12-15 22:00:18    NaN
19   A 2022-12-15 22:00:19    NaN
20   A 2022-12-15 22:00:20    NaN
21   A 2022-12-15 22:00:21    NaN
22   A 2022-12-15 22:00:22    NaN
23   A 2022-12-15 22:00:23    NaN
24   A 2022-12-15 22:00:24    NaN
25   A 2022-12-15 22:00:25    NaN
26   A 2022-12-15 22:00:26    NaN
27   A 2022-12-15 22:00:27    NaN
28   A 2022-12-15 22:00:28    NaN
29   A 2022-12-15 22:00:29    NaN
30   A 2022-12-15 22:00:30    0.0
31   A 2022-12-15 22:00:31    NaN
32   A 2022-12-15 22:00:32    NaN
33   A 2022-12-15 22:00:33    NaN
34   A 2022-12-15 22:00:34    NaN
35   A 2022-12-15 22:00:35    NaN
36   A 2022-12-15 22:00:36    NaN
37   A 2022-12-15 22:00:37    NaN
38   A 2022-12-15 22:00:38    NaN
39   A 2022-12-15 22:00:39    NaN
40   A 2022-12-15 22:00:40    NaN
41   A 2022-12-15 22:00:41    NaN
42   A 2022-12-15 22:00:42    NaN
43   A 2022-12-15 22:00:43    NaN
44   A 2022-12-15 22:00:44    NaN
45   A 2022-12-15 22:00:45    NaN
46   A 2022-12-15 22:00:46    NaN
47   A 2022-12-15 22:00:47    0.0
48   A 2022-12-15 22:00:48    NaN
49   A 2022-12-15 22:00:49    NaN
50   A 2022-12-15 22:00:50    NaN
51   A 2022-12-15 22:00:51    NaN
52   A 2022-12-15 22:00:52    NaN
53   A 2022-12-15 22:00:53    NaN
54   A 2022-12-15 22:00:54    NaN
55   A 2022-12-15 22:00:55    NaN
56   A 2022-12-15 22:00:56    NaN
57   A 2022-12-15 22:00:57    NaN
58   A 2022-12-15 22:00:58    NaN
59   A 2022-12-15 22:00:59    NaN
60   B 2022-12-15 22:00:00    NaN
61   B 2022-12-15 22:00:01    NaN
62   B 2022-12-15 22:00:02    NaN
63   B 2022-12-15 22:00:03    7.0
64   B 2022-12-15 22:00:04    NaN
65   B 2022-12-15 22:00:05    NaN
66   B 2022-12-15 22:00:06    NaN
67   B 2022-12-15 22:00:07    NaN
68   B 2022-12-15 22:00:08    NaN
69   B 2022-12-15 22:00:09    NaN
70   B 2022-12-15 22:00:10    NaN
71   B 2022-12-15 22:00:11    NaN
72   B 2022-12-15 22:00:12    NaN
73   B 2022-12-15 22:00:13    NaN
74   B 2022-12-15 22:00:14    NaN
75   B 2022-12-15 22:00:15    NaN
76   B 2022-12-15 22:00:16    NaN
77   B 2022-12-15 22:00:17    NaN
78   B 2022-12-15 22:00:18    NaN
79   B 2022-12-15 22:00:19    NaN
80   B 2022-12-15 22:00:20    NaN
81   B 2022-12-15 22:00:21    NaN
82   B 2022-12-15 22:00:22    NaN
83   B 2022-12-15 22:00:23    NaN
84   B 2022-12-15 22:00:24    NaN
85   B 2022-12-15 22:00:25    NaN
86   B 2022-12-15 22:00:26    NaN
87   B 2022-12-15 22:00:27    NaN
88   B 2022-12-15 22:00:28    NaN
89   B 2022-12-15 22:00:29    NaN
90   B 2022-12-15 22:00:30    5.0
91   B 2022-12-15 22:00:31    NaN
92   B 2022-12-15 22:00:32    NaN
93   B 2022-12-15 22:00:33    NaN
94   B 2022-12-15 22:00:34    NaN
95   B 2022-12-15 22:00:35    NaN
96   B 2022-12-15 22:00:36    NaN
97   B 2022-12-15 22:00:37    NaN
98   B 2022-12-15 22:00:38    NaN
99   B 2022-12-15 22:00:39    NaN
100  B 2022-12-15 22:00:40    NaN
101  B 2022-12-15 22:00:41    NaN
102  B 2022-12-15 22:00:42    NaN
103  B 2022-12-15 22:00:43    7.0
104  B 2022-12-15 22:00:44    NaN
105  B 2022-12-15 22:00:45    NaN
106  B 2022-12-15 22:00:46    NaN
107  B 2022-12-15 22:00:47    NaN
108  B 2022-12-15 22:00:48    NaN
109  B 2022-12-15 22:00:49    NaN
110  B 2022-12-15 22:00:50    NaN
111  B 2022-12-15 22:00:51    NaN
112  B 2022-12-15 22:00:52    NaN
113  B 2022-12-15 22:00:53    NaN
114  B 2022-12-15 22:00:54    NaN
115  B 2022-12-15 22:00:55    NaN
116  B 2022-12-15 22:00:56    NaN
117  B 2022-12-15 22:00:57    NaN
118  B 2022-12-15 22:00:58    NaN
119  B 2022-12-15 22:00:59    NaN
120  C 2022-12-15 22:00:00    NaN
121  C 2022-12-15 22:00:01    NaN
122  C 2022-12-15 22:00:02    NaN
123  C 2022-12-15 22:00:03    NaN
124  C 2022-12-15 22:00:04    NaN
125  C 2022-12-15 22:00:05    NaN
126  C 2022-12-15 22:00:06    NaN
127  C 2022-12-15 22:00:07    NaN
128  C 2022-12-15 22:00:08    NaN
129  C 2022-12-15 22:00:09    NaN
130  C 2022-12-15 22:00:10    0.0
131  C 2022-12-15 22:00:11    NaN
132  C 2022-12-15 22:00:12    NaN
133  C 2022-12-15 22:00:13    NaN
134  C 2022-12-15 22:00:14    NaN
135  C 2022-12-15 22:00:15    NaN
136  C 2022-12-15 22:00:16    NaN
137  C 2022-12-15 22:00:17    NaN
138  C 2022-12-15 22:00:18    NaN
139  C 2022-12-15 22:00:19    NaN
140  C 2022-12-15 22:00:20    NaN
141  C 2022-12-15 22:00:21    NaN
142  C 2022-12-15 22:00:22    NaN
143  C 2022-12-15 22:00:23    NaN
144  C 2022-12-15 22:00:24    NaN
145  C 2022-12-15 22:00:25    NaN
146  C 2022-12-15 22:00:26    NaN
147  C 2022-12-15 22:00:27    NaN
148  C 2022-12-15 22:00:28    NaN
149  C 2022-12-15 22:00:29    NaN
150  C 2022-12-15 22:00:30    NaN
151  C 2022-12-15 22:00:31    NaN
152  C 2022-12-15 22:00:32    NaN
153  C 2022-12-15 22:00:33    NaN
154  C 2022-12-15 22:00:34    3.4
155  C 2022-12-15 22:00:35    NaN
156  C 2022-12-15 22:00:36    NaN
157  C 2022-12-15 22:00:37    NaN
158  C 2022-12-15 22:00:38    NaN
159  C 2022-12-15 22:00:39    NaN
160  C 2022-12-15 22:00:40    NaN
161  C 2022-12-15 22:00:41    NaN
162  C 2022-12-15 22:00:42    NaN
163  C 2022-12-15 22:00:43    NaN
164  C 2022-12-15 22:00:44    NaN
165  C 2022-12-15 22:00:45    NaN
166  C 2022-12-15 22:00:46    NaN
167  C 2022-12-15 22:00:47    NaN
168  C 2022-12-15 22:00:48    NaN
169  C 2022-12-15 22:00:49    NaN
170  C 2022-12-15 22:00:50    NaN
171  C 2022-12-15 22:00:51    NaN
172  C 2022-12-15 22:00:52    NaN
173  C 2022-12-15 22:00:53    NaN
174  C 2022-12-15 22:00:54    NaN
175  C 2022-12-15 22:00:55    NaN
176  C 2022-12-15 22:00:56    NaN
177  C 2022-12-15 22:00:57    NaN
178  C 2022-12-15 22:00:58    NaN
179  C 2022-12-15 22:00:59    3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = {"timestamp": ["2022-12-15 22:00:00", "2022-12-15 22:00:30", "2022-12-15 22:00:47", 
                    "2022-12-15 22:00:03", "2022-12-15 22:00:30", "2022-12-15 22:00:43", 
                    "2022-12-15 22:00:10", "2022-12-15 22:00:34", "2022-12-15 22:00:59"],
    "ID": ["A","A","A",
            "B", "B", "B",
            "C", "C", "C"],
    "value": [11, 0, 0,
                7, 5, 7,
                0, 3.4, 3.4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["timestamp", "ID", "value"])
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])

#li = []

time_range = pd.date_range('2022-12-15 22:00:00', '2022-12-15 22:00:59', freq="S")


#for id in df.ID.unique():
#    for i in time_range:
#        li.append({'ID': id, 'timestamp': i})

#df1 = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_dict(li)]).drop_duplicates(['ID', 'timestamp']).sort_values(['ID', 'timestamp']).reset_index()

#print (df1)

df = (df.set_index('timestamp')
    .groupby('ID')['value']
    .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(time_range))
    .reset_index())
```

yields:

```
     index           timestamp ID  value
0        0 2022-12-15 22:00:00  A   11.0
1        0 2022-12-15 22:00:01  A    NaN
2        1 2022-12-15 22:00:02  A    NaN
3        2 2022-12-15 22:00:03  A    NaN
4        3 2022-12-15 22:00:04  A    NaN
..     ...                 ... ..    ...
173    172 2022-12-15 22:00:55  C    NaN
174    173 2022-12-15 22:00:56  C    NaN
175    174 2022-12-15 22:00:57  C    NaN
176    175 2022-12-15 22:00:58  C    NaN
177      8 2022-12-15 22:00:59  C    3.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works, but the answer from ouroboros1 is more elegant without any loops, I have therefor accepted that answer.

Comment: no worries. I added a different solution without loops.